# Class Diagram in C# for whole Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class-diagram

How can I create a class diagram for the whole solution? In the solution, there are some projects and I want to create a class diagramm from all of them.

I use Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: Not possible up to VS2008 and I'm almost positive that VS2010 doesn't provide this feature either. Why would you need such giant diagram anyway?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming. It should probably be posted on a different SE site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create class diagram just for project not for whole solution. You can use sequence diagram and class diagram to manage how everything is related.

Comment: For sequence diagrams you'd need Visual Studio Ultimate. The OP has Professional. Though, you are correct. You can not make a class diagram for a solution.

Comment: Good point @michael, thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what you mean by class diagram but you can check out [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org). It has support for C#. It is straightforward to use and works well.